# How to get value from HTML dialog input

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I get the value from the HTML dialog input?

This is what I have so far, if user ticks the box I want cell A1 to be set to true, otherwise false.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Menu')
      .addItem('Run something', 'doSomething')
      .addToUi();
}

function doSomething() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html.evaluate(),"Make a choice");
}
```

**HTML.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="all">
    <label for="all"> Tick if all</label>

    <button name="cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()">Cancel</button>
    <button name="ok" onclick="getValue()">OK</button>
  </body>

  <script>
    function getValue() {
    const all = document.getElementById('all').value;

    const spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    sheet.getRange('A1').setValue(all);

    google.script.host.close();
  }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting input value and sending it to the server and returning it back to success handler.

```
<script>
  function() allfunk() {
    google.script.withSuccessHandler( (rv) => {
      window.alert(`The value is ${rv}`)
    })
    .functionName(document.getElementById("all").value);
}
</script>
```

gs:

```
function functionName(v) {
  //dosomething with value and return rv;
  return rv;
}
```

- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)